# Asp.Net Web API documentation tools to support description editing

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I'm looking for a documentation tool or generator for asp.net web api application. The tool must allow to edit the description/ summary of the api methods or parameters.
I may need this, to allow different teams say PMs, QA to also edit the documentation, so that it doesn't always have to be developers.

Please suggest any good tools which supports this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

We've been using Swagger to document our APIs. This Nuget package Swashbuckle adds Swagger to your api project. https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle

Documentation is created with XML comments and displayed in a nice UI interface that you can even test your APIs from.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply. I agree with you.

Now, I'm looking for tool for online documentation which generates from my existing xml document. 
That online documentation could be able to edited further by team members and published.